# double negation rule - properties of semantic equivalence

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I know the rule for double negation is

```
¬(¬P) ≡ P
```

However if I have:

```
¬(¬P V Q)
```

does that give me

```
(P V Q)
```

or would the negation still apply to the Q:

```
(P V ¬Q)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Neither, you'd need DeMorgans to distribute the not over the or, to start with, which turns or into and.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NO**.

In :

> $¬(¬P \lor Q)$

we have **not** a case of *double negation*, because the outer $\lnot$ applies to all the sub-formula inside the parentheses.

We have to apply [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to transform it into the equivalent form :

> $\lnot \lnot P \land \lnot Q$

and then apply *double negation to get :

> > $P \land \lnot Q$.